# Convert SQL Server query to C# dynamic query fails

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server query that works perfectly well as a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "InputData_GetStatus" 
     @id VARCHAR(250) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @lookingFor NVARCHAR(36);

    SELECT @lookingFor = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36),  (SELECT TOP 1(UID) 
                                                 FROM StudyInput 
                                                 WHERE ID = @id));
    IF (@lookingFor IS NULL)
        RETURN;

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(2000);
    SET @query = 'select null as InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''StudyInput'' as TableName from StudyInput_InOut where OutUID = ''' + @lookingFor + '''';

    DECLARE @stepName VARCHAR(150);
    DECLARE @processUID uniqueidentifier;

    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
        SELECT stepName, ProcessUID 
        FROM StudyInput_DirectLink 
        WHERE InputUID = @lookingFor 


    OPEN MY_CURSOR 

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @stepName, @processUID 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @query = @query + ' union all ';
        SET @query = @query + 'select InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''' + @stepName + ''' as TableName from ' + @stepName + '_InOut where OutUID = ''' + convert(nvarchar(36), @processUID) + '''';

        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @stepName, @processUID;
    END 

    CLOSE MY_CURSOR;
    DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
END
```

In C# I have written code to create a database dynamically with dynamic tables and stored procedures.

I am trying to convert the query above to a string that I can execute to create it as a store procedure each time I create the database.

But it looks like my formatting is wrong because I keep getting the following error (or variations of it)

> Incorrect syntax near ''.
>   Incorrect syntax near ' + @stepName + '.

This is what I have now for the query in C#

```
private void SetupOtherQueries()
{
  string query = "";

  query += "declare @lookingFor nvarchar(36);";

  // Search for the UID of the InputKey associated to the Data Input we want to query the status for
  query += string.Format(" select @lookingFor = convert(nvarchar(36), (select top 1(UID) from StudyInput where {0} = @id));", this._config.InputKey);
  query += " if (@lookingFor is null) return;";

  query += " DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);";

  // Build a dynamic query to get the status of the data for each step it has been involved with
  // Starting with StudyInput
  query += " set @query = 'select null as InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''StudyInput'' as TableName from StudyInput_InOut where OutUID = ''' + @lookingFor + '''';";

  // Get all the direct links involving the Data
  // And build a dynamic query for each Step table
  query += " SELECT @query = COALESCE(@query + ' union all select InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''' + stepName + ''' as TableName from ' + stepName + '_InOut where OutUID = ''' + convert(nvarchar(36), ProcessUID) + '''', '')";
  query += " FROM StudyInput_DirectLink";
  query += " where InputUID = @lookingFor";

  // Execute the dynamic query
  query += " EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;";

  DB_Helpers.CreateStoredProcedure(
    this._config.StudyName,
    "InputData_GetStatus",
    String.Format("@id varchar({0})", MaxFieldSize),
    query);
}
```

Helper functions:

```
static public void CreateStoredProcedure(
  string db,
  string queryName,
  string parameters,
  string procedure)
{
  ExecuteQuery(
    db,
    String.Format("if exists(Select * from sysobjects where name = '{0}')  begin drop procedure {0} end; EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [{0}] {1} AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; {2}; END'",
      queryName,
      parameters,
      procedure));
}

static public void ExecuteQuery(
  string db,
  string query)
{
  SqlConnection connection = null;
  try
  {
    connection = new SqlConnection(string.Format(connectionString, db));
    connection.Open();

    // Creates DB
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  finally
  {
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem boils down to the number of ' that are required when building the query string.

But I just cannot figure out how many I need for it to be correctly formatted.

Edit:

This is the full query just before execution:

```
if exists(Select * from sysobjects where name = 'InputData_GetStatus')
begin drop procedure InputData_GetStatus end;
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [InputData_GetStatus] @id varchar(250) AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; declare @lookingFor nvarchar(36); select @lookingFor = convert(nvarchar(36), (select top 1(UID) from StudyInput where MINC = @id)); if (@lookingFor is null) return; DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX); set @query = 'select null as InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''StudyInput'' as TableName from StudyInput_InOut where OutUID = ''' + @lookingFor + ''''; SELECT @query = COALESCE(@query + ' union all select InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''' + stepName + ''' as TableName from ' + stepName + '_InOut where OutUID = ''' + convert(nvarchar(36), ProcessUID) + '''', '') FROM StudyInput_DirectLink where InputUID = @lookingFor EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;; END'
```

Comment: Side note: `throw ex;` should be `throw;`. This preserves the stack trace in the exception, otherwise it is reset to inside the `catch`

Comment: @igor, I put the ex because I have a debug breakpoint there. the final version will not have the catch because there is one at a higher level.

Comment: Tip: Attach the debugger and place a break point at the end before the query is executed. Copy the query as text and place it in SSMS and see if you get the same error there (most likely you will). That should give you a better idea of why the error is occurring.

Comment: @igor, I did that. But I still could not figure out what was wrong. I will edit the post to include that.

Comment: Your query is a stored procedure not a query.  I recommend you create stored procedure in then database and then call the stored procedure.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx

Comment: @jdweng as I specified, I cannot do that because the database it created dynamically. That is why I need to be able to dynamically create this stored procedure

Comment: You can print `query`, put the query in your SQL IDE and see what is missing with syntax coloration

Comment: @kobi I did that, and tried to fix it by adding the missing '. but I could not make it work. I got variations of the error I reported.

Comment: A query is a string and you should be able to add parameters to the stored procedure to make it dynamic.  An IF statement is not part of a query.  Use IIF instead of IF.

Comment: Sidebar: Use stringbuilder over string concatentation.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the need to use a cursor... SELECT by itself can build up strings. There's also the STUFF/FOR XML trick for building up strings and not having to worry about any trailing commas or cruft. Cursors should be avoided whenever possible, and it seems perfectly possible to avoid them here.

Comment: @pmbAustin thanks for the feedback. I have replaced the cursor with a query-built string instead. Still having the same issue though as before.

Comment: Seems to me you need to double down on your apostrophes further. You are creating dynamic SQL inside dynamic SQL, thus all your apostrophes would be doubled again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work after running a subset of the string query generated just before execution then adding more each time and comparing the output with the original query.

I'll post the final result here if anyone get the same problem and need to figure it out on their own query.

```
  string query = "";

  query += "declare @lookingFor nvarchar(36);";

  // Search for the UID of the InputKey associated to the Data Input we want to query the status for
  query += string.Format(" select @lookingFor = convert(nvarchar(36), (select top 1(UID) from StudyInput where {0} = @id));", this._config.InputKey);
  query += " if (@lookingFor is null) return;";

  query += " DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);";

  // Build a dynamic query to get the status of the data for each step it has been involved with
  // Starting with StudyInput
  query += " set @query = ''select null as InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, ''''StudyInput'''' as TableName from StudyInput_InOut where OutUID = '''''' + @lookingFor + '''''''';";

  // Get all the direct links involving the Data
  // And build a dynamic query for each Step table
  query += " SELECT @query = COALESCE(@query + '' union all select InUID, OutUID, InNext, Status, '''''' + stepName + '''''' as TableName from '' + stepName + ''_InOut where OutUID = '''''' + convert(nvarchar(36), ProcessUID) + '''''''', '''')";
  query += " FROM StudyInput_DirectLink";
  query += " where InputUID = @lookingFor;";

  // Execute the dynamic query
  query += " EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;";
```